# Array lenght is more than what is needed in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array in Javascript like this:

```
books[3] = 'abcds';
books[54] = 'point';
books[218] = 'qwerty';

alert(books.length);
```

218 is alerted instead of 3. I just need an array with 3 items not 218.

How can I solve it?

Comment: that would alert 219, not 218 - if you want 3 properties use an Object not an array - seriously, you didn't even get the question right!

Comment: What's the point/meaning of those keys? Why don't you use `books[0]`, `books[1]`, `books[2]`?

Answer (score 1):

`books[3]` will  add element in 4th place & 0-3 rd place will be empty ,similarly `books[218]` will place in 219th place.

So length will be `219`

Answer (score 1):

You could filter sparse elements with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean/) as callback.

This works for [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) items.

```js
var books = [];
books[3] = 'abcds';
books[54] = 'point';
books[218] = 'qwerty';

var allBooks = books.filter(Boolean);

console.log(allBooks.length);
console.log(allBooks);
```

For [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values, you need a different approach by iterating with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and push all items.

`forEach` visits only non sparse items.

```js
var books = [];
books[3] = 'abcds';
books[54] = 'point';
books[42] = undefined;
books[55] = 0;
books[218] = 'qwerty';

var allBooks = [];

books.forEach(a => allBooks.push(a));

console.log(allBooks.length);
console.log(allBooks);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing values at the mentioned index. You can store values in form of objects in an array.

```js
var books = [];
books.push({3:'abcds'});
books.push({54: 'point'});
books.push({218: 'qwerty'});
console.log(books.length);
```

Answer (score -1):

The way to get the count of values inside the array would be `Object.values(books).length`

Comment: Although I understand this is not the optimal structure for this variable and a bad practice, it is a solution to the question.